# Is it possible to scale two.js groups in one direction

Tags: two.js

Two.js seems to only support a single value for a scale, not x,y components. Is it possible to just stretch something horizontally?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, under the hood every `Two.Group` and `Two.Polygon` has a `_matrix` object. You can set `_matrix.manual` and then do a number of other transformations that you can't do with the typical two.js API. Check out [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jonobr1/jdojyzaw/) for a demonstration.